# How do I get my code to properly run on Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I'm interested in learning C++, and I've downloaded Visual Code Studio and Visual Code as well as Eclipse. Does anyone have any advice? When I say beginner, I mean absolute newcomer to coding.
How would you run code in Visual Studio (I've downloaded the CodeRunner extension for Visual Studio)?

When I input the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
 int main() 
 { 
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      
  std::cout << i  <<  "\n" ;
   }
}
```

into a website compiler, it pops out the loop but when I try to run it through Visual Studio it doesn't?

Any tips, the advice is welcome!

Comment: What error does the visual studio show? Share the screenshot when you run the code on the visual studio to get a better understanding.

Comment: How exactly are you running your code in Visual Studio? There is an option that will keep the console open until you press a key, so it may look like your program is stuck in the end.

Comment: are those instructions pasted into a file that belongs to a properly configured c++ project????

Comment: Did you download a compiler? https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/ _

Comment: There are Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. They have nothing in common. The CodeRunner extension is for VS Code. VS Code usually requires a non-trivial amount of configuration before it starts working.

Comment: Well I don't use VScode, but when I started programming, the first thing I did was to install a Compiler.

Comment: "_when i try to run it through Visual Studio it doesnt?_" What exactly did you try, and in which Visual Studio? As written, this seems too vague and too broad right now I'm afraid.

Comment: Start with a free [community edition of Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). It is an all-in-one solution that almost always works right out of the box. Visual Studio Code takes a bit of configuring and until you know  C++ better, you'll constantly be wondering, is my code bad or did I get the configuration wrong? Life is easier is you learn one thing at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not confusing yourself between Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code.

For running code inside VS, you will need to create a "Project", (a VS thing that contains all your source files)

When you open VS, you will have a "Open folder or project" window in front of you.
Select "Create a new project", Select "C++ Application", and then "Blank Project"

Thus you will be setup for writing code.

On the right hand side, you should have a tab that is named "Solution Explorer". Right click and select "Add New", and select "C++ File (.cpp)"

Name the .cpp file and paste your code in it.

Then, press F5 and a terminal that contains the output of your code should appear.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

The typical first program that a newcomer will write is to display the text "Hello world".  Such a program is called a *hello world* program, and you can look for a [*hello world* tutorial for Visual Studio in C++](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-tutorial-hello-world/) .  Such tutorials will cover the very basics of compiling and running your program and will often have very explicit step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

//Try return 0.This code is running in my vscode

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
 int main() 
 { 
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      
  cout << i  <<  "\n" ;
   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return` in `main` can be omitted.